# How to config Solr to exclude certain documents from search result?

Tags: search, solr

To exclude some documents from the search result, I can use the not in or - negative sign to specify the ids like this through a query.

```
select/?q=*:*&fq=-id:86+-id:338
```

This is ok if there are only a few ids needed to be excluded, but the query will be very very long if I have thousands of ids needed to be excluded from the search. I need to conditionally exclude a list of documents from the search result. How can I do it through solr configuration file such as creating an exclusion list? For example, I need to exclude the documents from search result if usstate is equal to NY, CA, VA, and zip code ending with 3

Comment: Add a new boolean field "exclude". Update the field in these documents with the value true. &fq=-exclude:true

Comment: yes, there is field like that can used to exclude them, but the requirement states not to use this field. Is there a way to do it through configuration?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [QueryElevationComponent](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/The+Query+Elevation+Component) to add a list of documents to exclude for a certain query. This will require you to perform a search that matches the query mentioned in the configuration file for it to work.

If you meant "i don't want to have any documents with usstate as NY, CA, VA where the zip code ends with 3" for your example, you're probably better off by just using that criteria directly in your query (with a modified version of `-(usstate:(NY OR CA OR VA) AND zipcode:*3)` to get the behavior you want) (see [ReverseWildcardFilterFactory](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#solr.ReversedWildcardFilterFactory) for faster reverse matches).

Comment: I need to exclude a list of docs regardless of the query string thus elevation will not work, correct? Instead of putting the query condition -(usstate:(NY OR CA OR VA) AND zipcode:*3) in a query itself, does solr allow you to put it in a config file so this condition will applied to all the incoming queries?